# attachments by outlook with strange filename using javax getFileName

Tags: java, outlook, multipart, outlook-web-app, javax

I'm using javax to get attachments from emails.
My code is here:

```
String disposition = part.getDisposition();
if (disposition != null &&
    (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT) || disposition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.INLINE))) {
    log.debug("Found attachment: " + part.getFileName());
}
```

and it works well. But when emails are sent by Outlook webmail with attachment with latin letters in the name, the part.getFileName() e.g. for the attachment "Riunione_del_venerdì.pdf" returns to me "=?iso-8859-1?Q?Riunione_del_venerd=EC_20170303.pdf?=" and I'm not able to get the correct name

How can I get the real filename ? How can I work this out ?

Answer (score 1):

After some time I found a solution by myself.
From javax.mail.internet I can use:

```
String filename = part.getFileName();
String decodedFilename = MimeUtility.decodeText(filename);
```

maybe just doing this only if filename starts with "=?" and ends with "?="